# How to feed a large number of samples in parallel to linux?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm trying run following command on a large number of samples.

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar                  \
     -R   scaffs_HAPSgracilaria92_50REF.fasta    \
     -T   HaplotypeCaller                         \
     -I   assembled_reads/{sample_name}.sorted.bam \
     --emitRefConfidence GVCF                       \
     -ploidy 1                                       \
     -nt  {number of cores}                           \
     -nct {number of threds}                           \
     -o   {sample_name}.raw.snps.indels.g.vcf
```

I have:

```
3312 cores,
  20 PB RAM of memory,
 110 TFLOPS of compute power
```

but I have thousands of these samples to process.

Each sample takes about a day or two to finish on my local computer.

I'm using a shared linux cluster and a job scheduling system called **`Slurm`**, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a submission script such as the following and submit it with the `sbatch` command.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=<nb of threads your Java application is able to use>
#SBATCH --mem=<number of MB of RAM your job needs>
#SBATCH --time=<duration of your job>
#SBATCH --array=1-<number of samples>

FILES=(assembled_reads/*.sorted.bam)

INFILE=${FILES[$SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID]}
OUTFILE=$(basename $INFILE .sorted.bam).raw.snps.indels.g.vcf

srun java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -R scaffs_HAPSgracilaria92_50REF.fasta -T HaplotypeCaller -I $INFILE --emitRefConfidence GVCF -ploidy 1 -nt 1-nct $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK -o $OUTFILE
```

This is totally untested, and only aims at giving you a first direction.

I am sure the administrators of the cluster you use have written some documentation, the first step would be to read it cover to cover.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  there isn't much documentation  to get you started.